# PHP preg pattern needed to get required data from html source

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm reading html source code and I need to get below data from it.

```
LMS.pageData['product']['maxThreshold'] ='6';
```

in above example I need to catch 6.

Comment: Does the provided example represent a fixed pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple capture grouping :

```
"LMS.pageData\['product'\]\['maxThreshold'\] ='(\d)';"
```

then you need to extract the 1st group from matched pattern!

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV5uG7/1)

You can also use look-around that returns the number directly without need to get the first group :

```
"(?<=LMS.pageData\['product'\]\['maxThreshold'\] =')\d(?=';)"
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, kindly give me a full sample code in PHP

Comment: @HamidJoukar SO is not a code writing service! you can simply search about the grubbing the groups from a match regex in preg!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the look-arounds to get a number inside `'...'` at the end of the line, like this:

```
<?php
$re = "#(?<=')\d+(?=';\s*$)#m"; 
$str = "LMS.pageData['product']['maxThreshold'] ='6';"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/fMwGJT)

Use `preg_match_all` to obtain multiple matches if input contains multiple lines with `'6';`s.